# Should Exception::Class objects evaluate to false in boolean context

Tags: perl

I'm trying Exception::Class for the first time and something that surprised me is that Exception::Class objects evaluate to true when returned from a function. Shouldn't the default be the opposite.

I know I can change this with overload but I am wondering if it's a good idea

```
sub gethtml{
    return MyException->new( error => 'some error' );
}
my $response = &gethtml  

if($response){
    #do something with the html 
}
else{
    #something went wrong check if it's an exception object
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect them to be false? Are you confusing them with returning false for failure?

Comment: @Schwern I added some code to the question. I want to be able to stop the function and tell the caller something went wrong without killing the whole program. 

for some reason I though and exception object would evaluate to false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing exceptions with returning a false value to indicate an error.

Part of the point of exceptions is that they provide their own channel to indicate error. This leaves `return` free to only return valid values. There's no need to check for false vs defined, or special objects, or do any per-function call error checking at all. It's all caught and dealt with at the end of the block.

If you return an exception object it defeats the point; they're not exceptions, they're just error codes.

To take advantage of exceptions, the code in your example should be written like this:

```
sub get_html {
    ...try to get the html...

    return $html if defined $html;

    MyException->throw( error => 'some error' );
}

eval { 
    my $html = get_html;
    # do something with $html;
}
if ( my $e = Exception::Class->caught() ) {
    ...deal with the error...
}
```

This can be made a bit prettier with [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny).

This makes more sense when you have to do a lot of things which might error, such as a bunch of file, network or database operations.  Look into modules such as [autodie](http://metacpan.org/release/autodie) and [Path::Tiny](http://metacpan.org/release/Path::Tiny) for how that works.

Answer (score 2):

You should not create one with `new` and return it. They have a `throw` method that acts as constructor and `die` automatically.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exception::Class qw( InputException HTTPException );
use Try::Tiny;

sub get_html {
  my ($url) = @_;

  # input validation
  InputException->throw(error => 'no URL') unless $url;

  my $res = $ua->get($url);
  if ($res->is_success) {
    # do more stuff with $res;
  } else {
    HTTPException->throw( error => 'request failed' );      
  }  
}

# ... later

my $url;
try {
  get_html($url);
} catch {
  # handle the error which is in $_
  if ( $_->isa('InputException') ) {
    print "You need to supply a URL";
  } elsif ( $_->isa('HTTPException') ) {
    print "Could not fetch the HTML because the HTTP request failed.\n";
    print "But I am not telling you why.";
  }
}
```

You can then go and `catch` them (use [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) for that) or simply wrap it in an eval. But basically those exceptions are simple objects. They are intended as the return value of `die` and get thrown around, so there is no need to return them anywhere.

Once the program dies, all the scopes on the call stack are exited forcefully until you end up in an `eval` block (which is what `catch` does). There, you can handle the error. And since that error is an object, you can do fancy stuff with it.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+          
| sub {                                                              |          
| +----------------------------------------------------------------+ |          
| | if () {                                                        | |          
| | +------------------------------------------------------------+ | |          
| | | foo:: sub {                                                | | |          
| | | +--------------------------------------------------------+ | | |          
| | | | catch {                                                | | | |          
| | | | +----------------------------------------------------+ | | | |          
| | | | | doo_stuff:: sub {                                  | | | | |          
| | | | | +------------------------------------------------+ | | | | |          
| | | | | |                                                | | | | | |          
| | | | | | MyException->throw ==> die $obj  +---------------------------------+
| | | | | | do_more_stuff(); # never executed              | | | | | |         |
| | | | | |                                                | | | | | |         |
| | | | | +------------------------------------------------+ | | | | |         |
| | | | +----------------------------------------------------+ | | | |         |
| | | |                                                        | | | |         |
| | | | handle_exception_in_catch($_)        <---------------------------------+
| | | | # ( in Try::Tiny the exception ends up in $_ )         | | | |          
| | | |                                                        | | | |          
| | | +--------------------------------------------------------+ | | |          
| | +------------------------------------------------------------+ | |          
| +----------------------------------------------------------------+ |          
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also see the [Exception::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::Class) docs.

---

If you mix exceptions and regular `die` or [Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp) `croak` calls, you will have to do a lot of checking if stuff is blessed before using `->isa`. [Safe::Isa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe::Isa) comes in handy here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exception::Class qw( InputException HTTPException );
use Try::Tiny;
use Safe::Isa;

sub get_html {
  my ($url) = @_;

  # input validation
  InputException->throw(error => 'no URL') unless $url;

  my $res = $ua->get($url);
  if ($res->is_success) {
    # do more stuff with $res;
    die "There is no answer in this HTML" if $res->decoded_content !~ m/42/;
  } else {
    HTTPException->throw( error => 'request failed' );      
  }  
}
```

With this code, the `$_->isa('...')` would blow up, because in case of the `die` call, `$_` is not an object and you cannot call the method `isa` on an unblessed reference (or non-reference). Safe::Isa provides a `$_isa`, which checks for that first and otherwise just returns `false`.

```
my $url;
try {
  get_html($url);
} catch {
  # handle the error which is in $_
  if ( $_->$_isa('InputException') ) {
    print "You need to supply a URL";
  } elsif ( $_->$_isa('HTTPException') ) {
    print "Could not fetch the HTML because the HTTP request failed.\n";
    print "But I am not telling you why.";
  }
}
```

For details on how that works, see [mst's talk *You did what?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aCsUxfRksE)

Comment: You should be checking exceptions by their class, not their message. I would recommend `use Exception::Class ( 'InputException' );`, `InputException->throw(error => 'no URL')` and `if $_->isa('InputException')`.

Comment: Indeed. I was lazy @Schwern ;)